# Error while Publishing on crafter deployer 2.5.10

Tags: crafter-cms

We are upgrading from 2.5.6 to 2.5.10. And we are getting this error after hitting approve and publish

ERROR] 2017-11-30 13:24:04,484 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] [deployment.SyncTargetDeployer] | Deployment failed for on target Internal Server Error. Deployment agent returned status {2}
[ERROR] 2017-11-30 13:24:04,484 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] [deployment.PublishingManagerImpl] | Deployment failed for bucket number 1 on target qa.
[ERROR] 2017-11-30 13:24:04,509 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] [job.PublishContentToDeploymentTarget] | Uploading content failed for site "mySite", target "qa", URL "http://localhost:9595/publish"
org.craftercms.studio.api.v1.service.deployment.UploadFailedException
    at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.deployment.SyncTargetDeployer.deployFiles(SyncTargetDeployer.java:211)
    at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.service.deployment.PublishingManagerImpl.deployItemsToTarget(PublishingManagerImpl.java:272)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor381.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.deployItemsToTarget(Unknown Source)
    at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.service.deployment.job.PublishContentToDeploymentTarget.processJobs(PublishContentToDeploymentTarget.java:119)
    at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.service.deployment.job.PublishContentToDeploymentTarget.executeAsSignedInUser(PublishContentToDeploymentTarget.java:77)
    at org.craftercms.studio.impl.v1.job.RepositoryJob.execute(RepositoryJob.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor178.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:321)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

Answer (score 0):

The only error message you posted is:
    Uploading content failed for site "mySite", target "qa", URL "http://localhost:9595/publish"

Please post the following:
1. The full stack trace (there should be a caused by)
2. Also in check the deployer log as well for additional details